# Django date field derived from timestamp field

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have a `created_date` field:

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want a field derived from `created_date` that ideally exists in the model. I know in *SQL* I can do:

```
SELECT created_date::date
FROM Comment
```

How would I define that in the Django model?

Edit: `created_date` is just an example so I can't use `date.today()` from `datetime` module. Also, note ultimate goal is to make a *slug* with a few different fields including the desired `date_only` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`__date`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date) when filtering or in `F`-expression, or for older versions of Django you can use the [**`TruncDate`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate).

So you can for example filter `Comment`s for a specific date with:

```
from datetime import date

Comment.objects.filter(created_date__date=date(2022, 4, 9))
```

Using `…_date` however makes not much sense: it is a `datetime` object, so the name of your field hints that it is a `DateField`, it might be better to use `created`, or `created_timestamp`.

Comment: Ultimately I want it in the model though, not as a lookup afterwards. Ideally so I can view on the admin page or produce a slug field. Is that possible with your solution?

Comment: @noblerthanoedipus: the `created_date` is a `datetime` object, so you can use `mycomment.created_date.year` to obtain the year, or `mycomment.created_date.date()` to obtain a `date` object.